# When using Microsoft Access, should we keep front-end masters in a shared folder and then have each person download a local copy?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, admin

Current Microsoft Access set up:

SharedNetworkDrive:\Engineering\AccessDB\ -- from here the db is split like this

SharedNetworkDrive:\Engineering\AccessDB\front-end &

SharedNetworkDrive:\Engineering\AccessDB\back-end

That being said, we have multiple departments using multiple front ends with a shared back-end file. I'm new to the project and I'm trying to develop an administrative front-end to log users off to perform maintenance on the back-end whenever there's a corrupt record.

To the question: Should users be using the front-ends located in the share drive, or should we continue distributing files of the front-ends that are to be saved locally on their desktops? Does it matter? Is there an alternative to make administrative tasks easier?

Comment: Users should use own copy installed on local drive or at least a copy in their own working folder. Users should not be opening the same file.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, best practice is for everyone to have their own copy of the front end. A common practice is to create a script file (batch, vbscript, powershell, or even another small Access app) which copies the latest version of the front end from a file server to the user's computer and then starts that front end.  Place the script file on the file server as well and create a shortcut on each user's computer to run it.